# How to submit a py2app created program to the Mac app store?

Tags: app-store, py2app

I've developed a program named [FMiner](http://www.fminer.com/), it's a web scraping software base on [PySide](https://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)(webkit). I moved it to Mac OS X with Py2App, and made it to a dmg file with the script like this:

```
os.system(r'macdeployqt fminer.app’)
os.system(r'hdiutil create fminer-mac-' +gdata.VERSION + r'.dmg -volname "fminer" -fs HFS+ -srcfolder "dist"')
```

It work fine, when people download and install it.

But how to submit it to app store? I just found this link: [Is it possible to deploy a Python application on the Mac App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940273/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-python-application-on-the-mac-app-store), but it's outdate. And I'm not family with xcode, I need the details of steps.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a comprehensive article explaining how to build and submit a Python app to the Mac App Store. It includes source code and build scripts for a barebones example app that I have successfully submitted.

- [Submitting a Python App to the Mac App Store](http://dafoster.net/articles/2014/06/24/submitting-a-python-app-to-the-mac-app-store/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=pymas)

Comment: Very thanks, I will try this. My app use PySide, do you know whether PySide used "Deprecated APIs"?

Comment: In my initial testing with PySide, the app that py2app built crashed on launch. If you determine how to fix that and let me know, I'll update my example app.